# R, missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r, if-statement

I trying to check if two variables have the same sign this is the code I am using.

```
a <- c(0)
x1 <- x/abs(x)
y1 <- y/abs(y)
if(x1==y1) {
  a <- x + y
  } else {
  a <- x - y
}
```

But I get the error

```
Error in if (x1 == y1) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there a more efficient way to check the signs?

Comment: try `sign` to check the signs

Comment: Possibly x or y are equal to zero. So you have x1 or y1 equal to NaN which cause expression x1==y1 equal to NA. NA raise an error in "if(x1==y1)". As recommended above use 'sign' function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining your operations together and using the `sign` function, you might try:

```
a <- ifelse(sign(x) == sign(y), x + y, x - y)
```

NB. `sign(0)` returns `0`